# How to receive data notifications in swift (FCM)

Tags: swift, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I need to receive data notifications in swift and not use Notification Message. Only use Data message.

this is my Json for postman

```
{

"to": "e32uafd....",

    "data": {
        "urlImage": "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/80/image.jpg",
        "title": "title",
        "body": "****body****.",
        "mutable_content": true
    }
}
```

this is my code in swift

```
@available(iOS 10.0, *)
    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,  willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler   completionHandler: @escaping (_ options:   UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void)
    {
                switch UIApplication.shared.applicationState
                    {
                    case .active:
                        completionHandler( [.alert,.sound])
                        break
                    default:
                        completionHandler( [.alert,.sound])
                        break
                          }
                             }
        }   
  }
```

Comment: did you solve it?

Answer (score 0):

You can get your notification data using `func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void)` but before you can do that you must make your ViewController  to be a delegate of  `UNUserNotificationCenter` When registering for notifications or in `didFinishLaunchWithOptions(:)` method.

**Step 1**
Make your AppDelegate to be a delegate of UNNotificationCenter

```
 func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

     // Assumming you have imported NotificationCenter
     UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
    //......

        return true
    }
```

**Step 2**
Get your info

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {

     print(userInfo) // Your notification info
    // Note that you have to cast/parse it depending on which data you want to handle. 


    }
```

Comment: You must assign your app delegate as the delegate of ```UNUserNotificationCenter``` when registering for notifications.  I have edited my answer just to be clear.

Comment: Are you sure that your app receives push notiications?

Comment: No, I do not receive notifications. but if I add "notification": {
        "title": "title",
        "body": "****body****.",
        "mutable_content": true
    },  
I receive notifications but that's the problem, I don't need to use the notification message. Only use the data message